# Ansible item when clause throws error: Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string

Tags: ansible

In the following task, I am getting the error message `Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string. Make sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-'.` I have traced it down to the `when` clause.

Using debug statements I have verified:

- `mysql_server_version='5.2.23'`
- `mysql_client_version='5.2.23'`
- `mysql_version='5.2.23'`

If I remove the `when` statement, the task runs.

```
 - name: download MySQL packages
   tags:
     - preosupdates
   when: "{{ mysql_server_version | version_compare(mysql_version, '<') or mysql_client_version | version_compare(mysql_version, '<') }}"
   command: yum update -y --downloadonly MySQL-server-advanced-{{ mysql_version }} MySQL-shared-compat-advanced-{{ mysql_version }} MySQL-client-advanced-{{ mysql_version }}
   register: downloadonly
   failed_when: downloadonly.rc not in (1, 0)
   changed_when: "downloadonly is defined and 'No Packages marked for Update' not in downloadonly.stdout"
```

#### Versions

- ansible-1.9.0.1

Comment: 1. Perhaps `or` isn't supported with `|`. See if `when: "{{ mysql_server_version | version_compare(mysql_version, '<') }}"` works or not. 2. (less likely, but) perhaps it doesn't resolve `mysql_version`. Can you try replacing with `mysql_version` with `'5.2.23'`, just to check? I can post an answer based on your answers.

Comment: Isolate the bug by making the when condition smaller and smaller. Start with `when: True` and run that one task by unique tag. Then replace with small condition and run again. Then replace with bigger condition and so on.

Comment: I wonder if its operator precedence between pipe operator and or operator, let me know if you find solution OP.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement), `when` conditions do not need to use the template markers `{{` and `}}` since those are already implied.

Try this instead:

```
when: mysql_server_version | version_compare(mysql_version, '<') or 
      mysql_client_version | version_compare(mysql_version, '<')
```